# python azure webApp, with openai

Tags: python, azure

I'm doing something wrong, i'm new and i'm not sure what.

I'm using this a base template and just trying to get a response from openai and display it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=flask%2Cmac-linux%2Cvscode-aztools%2Cvscode-deploy%2Cdeploy-instructions-azportal%2Cterminal-bash%2Cdeploy-instructions-zip-azcli

I think my indents are messed up, but i'm not certain.

I get an error on line27 about indents.

openai.api_type = "azure"  is the line with the error.

```
import os
import openai

from flask import (Flask, redirect, render_template, request,
                   send_from_directory, url_for)

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
   print('Request for index page received')
   return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'),
                               'favicon.ico', mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')

@app.route('/hello', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
   name = request.form.get('name')
   openai.api_type = "azure"
   openai.api_base = "https://itsavvy.openai.azure.com/"
   openai.api_version = "2022-12-01"
   openai.api_key = os.getenv("jjjj")


   response = openai.Completion.create(
     engine="ITsavvy",
     prompt=name,
     temperature=1,
     max_tokens=100,
     top_p=0.5,
     frequency_penalty=0,
     presence_penalty=0,
     stop=None)





   if name:
       print('Request for hello page received with name=%s' % response)
       return render_template('hello.html', name = response)
   else:
       print('Request for hello page received with no name or blank name -- redirecting')
       return redirect(url_for('index'))


if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run()
```

Just looking to get an openai response.

Comment: Do you always use a tab and don't mix tab and space?

Can you provide a stack trace?

Comment: Best thing to do is to install a code formatter in the IDE and format the code.

Comment: I suggest installing black (https://pypi.org/project/black/) and running `black myfile.py` to auto-format your code.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I created a **openai_Api key** through this [link](https://auth0.openai.com/u/login/identifier?state=hKFo2SBqNURmdFBveERKVWdNaHY0QUtmWTZ3MHRfdmRPMGRRcKFur3VuaXZlcnNhbC1sb2dpbqN0aWTZIFc1MERFb3hQbEdpdWtWY2lqeGI4WFJGQngta1lfSlJlo2NpZNkgRFJpdnNubTJNdTQyVDNLT3BxZHR3QjNOWXZpSFl6d0Q) as below,

[image]

I tried this [Github](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/msdocs-python-flask-webapp-quickstart/blob/main/app.py) code to get **openai response**.

**Code:**

**[test.py](http://test.py):**

```py
import os
import openai
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, send_from_directory, url_for

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    print('Request for index page received')
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/favicon.ico')
def favicon():
    return send_from_directory(os.path.join(app.root_path, 'static'), 'favicon.ico', mimetype='image/vnd.microsoft.icon')

@app.route('/hello', methods=['POST'])
def hello():
    name = request.form.get('name')
    openai.api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"

    response = openai.Completion.create(
        engine="davinci",
        prompt=name,
        temperature=1,
        max_tokens=100,
        top_p=0.5,
        frequency_penalty=0,
        presence_penalty=0,
        stop=None
    )

    if name:
        print('Request page with name=%s' % response)
        return render_template('hello.html', name=response)
    else:
        print('Request page with no name -- redirecting')
        return redirect(url_for('index'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

***index.html:***

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Flask Application</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Welcome to My Flask Application</h1>
  <p>This is the index page.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

***hello.html:***

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello, {{ name }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

**Output:**

**[test.py](http://test.py)** file run successfully as below,

[image]

With the above mentioned **URL**, got the result in **Postman**.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]

With the above mentioned **URL**, got the result in **Postman**.

[image]

**Reference:**

Check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-python?tabs=flask,mac-linux,vscode-aztools,vscode-deploy,deploy-instructions-azportal,terminal-bash,deploy-instructions-zip-azcli) to know more about deploying a Python (Django or Flask) web app to Azure App Service.